# Does iOS app give as gift use money?

Tags: ios, app-store

Hi i would like to give my iOS app to my friends as gift in App Store.

I am developer of this app , so when i give my app to my friends as gift in app store , does it's use my money?

It's cost my money for my app to give as gift?

Sorry if my questions bother you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get promo codes from iTunes Connect.

Comment: how can i do that?Is there anyways step by step? Thanks.

Comment: You have to login to iTunes connect first, then choose the app you want to generate a promo code for. Click on the "View Details" or "Edit" button on your desired app to view its details. In the app details page, at the top right corner, there is a blue "generate promo" code button. This is what NSPostWhenIdle said, in case you didn't read his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Gifting is something you can do with any app not just yours, and yes it does cost you money. To generate promo codes for your app login to iTunes Connect and choose your app in the manage apps section. Then simply choose the version of your app and there is a promo codes link.

Futhermore, please read the FAQ before posting again on this site.